# WSDL: No element type is defined for message

Tags: web-services, wsdl, apache-axis, bpel, apache-ode

I'm creating a service orchestration using Eclipse BPEL Designer plugin and i have a problem with the WSDL file that it generates automatically.

Here is the WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
   <definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:plnk="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://ws.invocation.import" xmlns:vprop="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/varprop" xmlns:wsdl="http://services.lolsystem.it" name="ImportOrchestration" targetNamespace="http://ws.invocation.import">

   <plnk:partnerLinkType name="ImportType">
      <plnk:role name="ImportRole" portType="wsdl:ImportServicePortType"/>
   </plnk:partnerLinkType>
   <import location="ImportModule.wsdl" namespace="http://services.italsystem.it"/>
<types>
   <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://ws.invocation.import">

     <element name="ImportOrchestrationRequest" type="tns:ImportOrchestrationReqType">
           </element>

   <element name="singleEntry">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element minOccurs="0" name="name" nillable="true" type="string"/>
                    <element minOccurs="0" name="content" nillable="true" type="base64Binary"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>

              <element name="ImportOrchestrationResponse">
            <complexType>
                <sequence>
                    <element name="result" type="string"/>
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
        </element>

        <complexType name="ImportOrchestrationReqType">
            <sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <element name="file" type="tns:SingleFile"></element>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>

        <complexType name="SingleFile">
            <sequence>
                <element name="name" type="string"></element>
                <element name="content" type="base64Binary"></element>
            </sequence>
        </complexType>
    </schema>
</types>


<message name="ImportOrchestrationRequestMessage">
    <part name="payload" type="tns:ImportOrchestrationReqType"/>
</message>
<message name="ImportOrchestrationResponseMessage">
    <part element="tns:ImportOrchestrationResponse" name="payload"/>
</message>


<!-- portType implemented by the ImportOrchestration BPEL process -->
<portType name="ImportOrchestration">
    <operation name="process">
        <input message="tns:ImportOrchestrationRequestMessage"/>
        <output message="tns:ImportOrchestrationResponseMessage"/>
    </operation>
</portType>   

<plnk:partnerLinkType name="ImportOrchestration">
    <plnk:role name="ImportOrchestrationProvider" portType="tns:ImportOrchestration"/>
</plnk:partnerLinkType>


<binding name="ImportOrchestrationBinding" type="tns:ImportOrchestration">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="process">
        <soap:operation soapAction="http://ws.invocation.import/process"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </input>
        <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>


<service name="ImportOrchestration">
    <port binding="tns:ImportOrchestrationBinding" name="ImportOrchestrationPort">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ode/processes/ImportOrchestration"/>
    </port>
</service>
</definitions>
```

Now, the problem is that Eclipse for Eclipse validator the WSDL is well formed.
I'm using Apache ODE as a BPEL engine, who is based on Axis2.
The problemi is that Axis engine give me an error when i try to deploy my BPEL proces, and it is:

"No element type is defined for message ImportOrchestrationRequestMessage"

Does someone can give me some advice to understand this error and how to correct it?
thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you try following
`<message name="ImportOrchestrationRequestMessage">
    <part name="payload" element="tns:ImportOrchestrationRequest"/>
</message>`

The problem is your binding is document literal, in that case the message part should be configured by using "element" rather than the "type"

HTH